Disabling options for xml feeds
I would like to disable xml feeds on my site and "disable xml feeds" plugin pretty much does the job. But I would like to keep main feed and category feeds available. The best would be to keep only main feed and one specific category feed, everything else I would like to disable.
I am only finding solutions how to disable all. Can you help me with the code that I can use to decide which feeds I want to enable/disable?
